# Magento 2 : Add ID or Class to checkout zip code input

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need to add a ID or Class in the zip code input field on checkout page, but I can't find where this element is rendered.

Any suggestion?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

The input is rendered with: `magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/input.html`. While you could override it, it is used very broadly.

My recommendation is to specify a custom template. This would be done via the following approximate steps:

- Copy the `input.html` into a module under a similar directory `view/frontend/web/templates/...`
- Create `checkout_index_index.xml` and create a deep XML structure to target `postcode` and specify an `elementTmpl`. The last `<item/>`s are: `shippingAddress` > `children` > `shipping-address-fieldset` > `children` > `postcode`.
- The postcode item would be something like this:

---

```
<item name="postcode">
    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">MyCompany_MyModule/element/postcode</item>
</item>
```